# music tex needed after package update?

Tags: packages, miktex, updating

I did a clean installation of MiKTeX (latest version).  Then I did a package update --- believe it or not, there were packages to update.

After the update, I tried running "Update Formats" from the settings...  I started getting mesages that I needed to install file having to do with music tex: bagpipe something or other, and some other file having to do with music notation.

That is surely a bug, right?  My sources are typeset correctly (so far), and they have nothing to do with music.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the bagpipe and bagpipex from the format list via the MiKTeX options (-> Formats ->"select" -> Remove). You won't be asked to install this package again.

Comment: Its forbiden. BuThe error message indicates "Built-in format definitions may not be deleted" and the format build processes, stops on those formats because I deleted music packages.

Answer (score 1):

Someone has told me this happens because the bagpipe package hasn't been properly categorized as a Music Application and is mistakenly considered essential.  Not exactly a bug, I guess, but not a good thing.